# If roots of a polynomial are complex number how to visualize Geometrically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have one basic doubt in complex numbers. We know that if a polynomial equation $P(x)=0$ cuts the $X$ axis or touches the $X$ axis, then they represent Real roots of the polynomial or real roots with repetition.

But how about the polynomials with no real roots. For example:

$$x^3-1=0$$ has one real toot $x=1$ which cuts $X$ axis at $(1,0)$. But its other two roots are $w$ and $w^2$. How to graphically visualize $w$ and $w^2$

Comment: You can visualize the complex numbers as $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, $\omega,\omega^2$ corresponds to the points on the unit circle making the angle $\frac{2\pi}3$ with the $x$-axis. But, I guess you don't want this visualisation?

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, in the complex plane the n roots of $z^n= 1$ (the nth roots of unity) are the vertices of the regular n sided polygon circumscribed by the unit circle.  In particular the cube roots of unity are the vertices of an equilateral triangle, the fourth roots of unity are the vertices of a square (with vertices at 1, i, -1, and -i), the fifth roots of unity are the vertices of a regular pentagon, etc.